# Stack Overflow, Google and Gemini

Tags: discussion

As contributors to this website, [this is something to be aware of.](https://techcrunch.com/2024/02/29/google-brings-stack-overflows-knowledge-base-to-gemini/) Personally, I am against it. What do you all think?

A related article, in the Communications of the ACM: [Generative AI Degrades Online Communities](https://cacm.acm.org/opinion/generative-ai-degrades-online-communities/).

Answer (score 1):

Provided SE sticks with [the license I agreed with](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing), I don't have much to complain about.  It's probably going to be hard for them to meet the **attribution** condition.

> You must give appropriate credit , provide a link to the license, and
> indicate if changes were made . You may do so in any reasonable
> manner, but not in any way that suggests the licensor endorses you or
> your use.

Comment: Agreed -- we have nothing to complain about. Given the changing landscape, though, I may not agree to the license in the future. I'm also curious about how they'll handle attribution, as you point out, since this is currently a problem for all chatbots.